# Ordenar um array de string em Swift utilizando uma função

Tags: array, ios, swift, algoritmo

Estou precisando de uma ajuda para resolver o seguinte problema de lógica de programação em Swift.

A tarefa consiste em organizar o array abaixo de forma descendente utilizando uma função.

Descrição:
Você deve implementar um algoritmo que receba uma lista de strings com formato específico e a retorne ordenada de forma descendente. Cada string será um mês em que a TAG entregou suas caixinhas para os associados do clube (ex: “janeiro/2017”, “março/2018”, “abril/2016”). A ordenação deve ser feita de forma descendente (mais recente para mais antigo) Seu algoritmo deve ser uma função, escrita em Swift 4.x, cuja chamada deve ser feita da seguinte maneira:

```
let mesesTag = [ "janeiro/2018", "novembro/2017", "fevereiro/2018", "março/2017", "julho/2016", "março/2018" ]

let mesesTagOrdenados = ordenar(mesesTag)

print(mesesTagOrdenados)

// resultado para este exemplo deve ser: // [ "março/2018", "fevereiro/2018", "janeiro/2018", "novembro/2017", "março/2017", "julho/2016" ]
```

Comment: Rodrigo, por favor adicione o código da sua solução e explique o que não está funcionando. Do jeito que está descrita a pergunta atualmente soa como "Resolva minha tarefa de programação".

Answer (score 5):

Caro Rodrigo,

A atividade desenvolvida pelo seu instrutor visa aprimorar seus conhecimentos e vai por mim cara isso é muito importante em nossa área. Não sinta-se satisfeito em receber a solução de um problema, assim você nada aprende e vira um desenvolvedor ctr+c, ctr+v, cara, tenta fazer, posta o código aqui que teremos prazer em te ajudar, mas tente fazer....

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim:

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - Funções

func ordenar(_ meses: [String]) -> [String] {

    let df = DateFormatter(dateFormat: "MMMM/yyyy")
    let mesesEmData = meses.map { (mes) -> Date? in df.date(from: mes) }
    let mesesEmDataSemNulos = mesesEmData.flatMap { $0 }

    let mesesOrdenados = mesesEmDataSemNulos.sorted(by: { (mes1, mes2) -> Bool in
        mes1.compare(mes2) == .orderedAscending
    })

    return mesesOrdenados.map { df.string(from: $0) }
}

extension DateFormatter {
    convenience init(dateFormat: String) {
        self.init()
        self.dateFormat = dateFormat
        self.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
    }
}

// MARK: - Questão

let mesesTag = [ "janeiro/2018", "novembro/2017", "fevereiro/2018", "março/2017", "julho/2016", "março/2018" ]

let mesesTagOrdenados = ordenar(mesesTag)

print(mesesTagOrdenados)
```

Log:

```
["julho/2016", "março/2017", "novembro/2017", "janeiro/2018", "fevereiro/2018", "março/2018"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Concordo com o Rafael Leão que você deveria colocar seu código pra gente te ajudar a resolver seu problema, mas como estava com tempo livre, aqui vai:

```
let mesesTag = [ "janeiro/2018", "novembro/2017", "fevereiro/2018", "março/2017", "julho/2016", "março/2018" ]       
let mesesTagOrdenados = ordenar(mesesTag)
print(mesesTagOrdenados)

enum months: String {
    case janeiro, fevereiro, marco, abril, maio, junho, julho, agosto, setembro, outubro, novembro, dezembro
}

func ordenar(_ meses: [String]) -> [String] {
    var splittedArray = [[String]]()
    for mes in meses {
        let splitted = mes.split(separator: "/")
        let first = String(splitted[0])
        let second = String(splitted[1])
        splittedArray.append([first, second])
    }

    let yearOrdered = splittedArray.sorted(by: sortByYear)
    let monthOrdered = yearOrdered.sorted(by: sortByMonth)

    let result = monthOrdered.map { (item) -> String in
        item.joined(separator: "/")
    }

    return result
}

func sortByYear(_ s1: [String], _ s2: [String]) -> Bool {
    let anoS1 = s1.last!
    let anoS2 = s2.last!

    if anoS1 > anoS2 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func sortByMonth(_ s1: [String], _ s2: [String]) -> Bool {
    let mesS1 = months(rawValue: s1.first!.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "ç", with: "c"))!.hashValue
    let mesS2 = months(rawValue: s2.first!.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "ç", with: "c"))!.hashValue
    let anoS1 = s1.last!
    let anoS2 = s2.last!

    if mesS1 > mesS2 && anoS1 >= anoS2 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```